# Basic Java, Largest and smallest integer

Tags: java

The purpose for the code is to prompt the user for 10 integers and then display the largest and smallest integer. I was able to ask the user for the 10 integers and display the largest number; however, the smallest number isn't shown. I believe the issue is with me setting smallest to 0.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class LargeSmall {
 public static void main(String[] args) {

 int counter = 1;
 int largest = 0; 
 int smallest = 0;
 int number = 0;  

 Scanner input= new Scanner(System.in);

 while (counter <= 10) {
     System.out.print("Enter number: ");
     number = input.nextInt();
     if (number > largest) {
         largest = number;
     }else if(number < smallest) {
         smallest = number;  
     }else {
         System.out.print("Number isn't distinct");   
         counter = counter + 1;
     }  

     System.out.println("Largest number is: " + largest);
     System.out.println("Smallest number is: " + smallest);
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you post a sample of numbers you have tried with and the problem arises?

Comment: You seem to have a good grasp of exactly what your problem is. Which raises the question of what are you asking?

Comment: You can also change `counter = counter + 1;` into `counter++;` , which does th same thing in less characters.

Comment: Not sure why you are doing this : `System.out.print("Number isn't distinct");` Should your program handle duplicates differently?

Comment: What happens if `number` is negative?

Comment: You are starting with `0` so the smallest has to be less than 0 to change this value. Similarly, if all your numbers are less than 0, your largest will be 0.

Answer (score 2):

Initialize your values like this so we guarantee that we start with the smallest/largest possible reference for our numbers to compare against to:

```
int largest = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
int smallest = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
int number;
int old = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
```

...and then some tweaks have to be made:

- Change the way you check for dupe numbers (use and `old` variable).
- Check if every new number is smaller than `smallest` number always (so, in the first iteration we assign the first value to `smallest` and `largest`)

Like this:

```
 number = input.nextInt();
 if (old != number) {
     old = number;
     if (number > largest) {
         largest = number;
     } 
     if(number < smallest) {
         smallest = number;  
     }
    /* consider moving next line here (this will guarantee to go to the next
       iteration only if the numbers are different, and get in the final messages,
       valid values for `smallest` and `largest` */
    // counter = counter + 1;
 } else {
      System.out.print("Number isn't distinct");
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Just make `>` into `>=` and `<` into `<=

Since `0 < 0` evaluates to `false`, your code block does not run. Thus the correction.

Answer (score 0):

Variable `smallest` is always 0 so the program never go into this block `else if(number < smallest)` 
You should add this code before `if(number < smallest)`

```
    if(smallest == 0) {
         smallest = number;
    }
```

Also your code doesn't catch the distinct numbers. To find the distinct number you should define a list `List<Integer> numbers = null;` at the start of the program.

Then you can check if the input is entered or not in the `while` loop like this:

```
   if(numbers.contains(number))
        System.out.print("Number isn't distinct");
    else 
        numbers.add(number);
```

Answer (score 0):

Sets the largest and smallert variables with the user's first input and then compare

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class LargeSmall {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.print("Enter number: ");
        Scanner input= new Scanner(System.in);
        int number = input.nextInt();
        int counter = 1;
        int largest = number; 
        int smallest = number;


        while (counter < 10) {
           System.out.print("Enter number: ");
           number = input.nextInt();
           if (number > largest) {
               largest = number;
           }else if(number < smallest) {
               smallest = number;  
           }else 
               System.out.print("Number isn't distinct");   

           counter = counter + 1;
       }  

       System.out.println("Largest number is: " + largest);
       System.out.println("Smallest number is: " + smallest);
    }
}
```